I am not getting the correct ask or bid value when using the Optiondata formula in google sheets
I am using google sheets to get the 'bid' and 'ask' for AAPL stock option, however when entering this formula =optiondata(AAPL241227C245, "bid") I am getting the incorrect value of 1.74.  The bid and ask is 2.19 and 2.30.  I followed this document and still getting the incorrect value.  I am having this issue with any other stock.  Please assist if I am doing something wrong.

This site is for questions regarding programming. I think that the missing double quote issue qualifies as a valid issue, but any unexpected result you get from a commercial tool should be discussed with the developers — they're the best qualified to answer that.

The example given in the document you link to is:
=optiondata("SPY230120C00400000", "bid")

The formula you quote is missing double quotes. Add them like this:
=optiondata("AAPL241227C245", "bid")


I am getting the incorrect value of 1.74. The bid and ask is 2.19 and 2.30

It is unclear why you think 1.74 would be incorrect and 2.30 would be correct. If the problem is with the Market Data app, you should probably contact the developers of the app.

You can try this Approach.
My formula is based on the document you referred to, which discusses Historical Options Prices in Google Sheets.

When passing just one or two parameters to the formula as shown in
this example, you will always get the most current option price.
However, you can also get historical options prices for contracts that
are no longer traded by using additional parameters. You can get
historic prices for a single options symbol by passing a third
parameter to the function: date. This works the same way as Google
Finance. For example, =OPTIONDATA("SPY230120C00400000", "price", "1/25/2021"). You can use “price”, “mark”, or “mid” as a parameter,
all three will return the midpoint price for the option. “Bid” and
“ask” can also be used if you would like historic bid/ask prices. And
again, you can use “all” to get all contract information.

Note: For live prices you must authorize a broker connection. Market Data does not provide real-time options prices without a connection to your broker.
For bid
=OPTIONDATA("AAPL241227C245", "bid", "12/2/2024")

For ask
=OPTIONDATA("AAPL241227C245", "bid", "12/2/2024")

Sample Data
For bid

For ask

Validation
=OPTIONDATA("AAPL241227C245", "all", "12/2/2024")


Reference

Market Data

